# Web presentation layer for different browsers and screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, presentation

I think I have some minimum foundation in HTML5 and CSS3. Currently there is much diversity of devices: conventional computer web browsers, mobile browsers, browsers tablets, etc, all with some limitations especially concerning screen resolution. This makes the development of a website, in relation to the presentation layer is somewhat more complicated, since it is difficult in all browsers on different devices display the website correctly and as intended .. I know that this knowledge is gained primarily through experience, but .. Is there any book, website or resource that expose these problems and advice or guidance on how to deal with them?

Thank you very much in advance.
Greetings!

Comment: If you think doing web development is difficult you should have tried in the pre-firebug era! I wouldn't recommend books for cross browser/device issues, by the time they get out of press they're already out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these resources :

http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile

http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design (Book)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Web_Development/Responsive_Web_design

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/the-mobile-web-optimization-guide/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/22/responsive-web-design-techniques-tools-and-design-strategies/